# How to grep for a line that has the same number you both need and don't need

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

This isn't at all easy to explain but easy to just show.

I have lines in a file such as:

```
100Dollars              3              IP  
200Dollars              3              IP
300Dollars              4              IP
```

I need to grep for lines that have no '3' in the second column. I tried the following:

```
egrep -v '3' filename
```

However this does not return the third line due to having a 3 in the first part of it. There's my basic question, if that makes sense.

How do I exclude what is in the first column and only grep for whatever is in the second column?

Comment: You say "2nd column" then you say "third column"; which is it?

Comment: 2nd column.  Fixed.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do `grep -v " 3 "`, assuming the columns are delimited by spaces?

Comment: Gave this a shot, does not work.  Opened the file in vim and it looks like it is separated by tabs in the columns, not spaces.

Comment: @roger34: Then use tabs... duh.

Comment: Did, it didn't work.

Comment: Try `grep -v '[[:space:]]3[[:space:]]'` or `grep -v '\<3\>'`.

Comment: Mikel the second regex worked.  Thanks.  Now I have to investigate why it works and learn from it.

Comment: @roger34 the metacharacters \< and \> match 'beginning of word' and 'end of word'. So it can match a bare 3, but not with 300, since the 3 in 300 is not end of anything.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
awk '$2 != 3' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to step up to awk or grep, which can do columns (among many other things)

```
gawk '$1 ~ /3/ && $2 !~ /3/{print $0}' < filename
```

Should do it.

This looks for a 3 in the first column (Columns are numbered starting by 1 in awk, $0 is the whole line) and not a 3 in the second column, and if so print the whole line ($0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
grep -v -P '\t3\t' filename
```

`-P` is a perl-style regular expression matcher.